# How can I determine the arguments for a private API function?

Tags: macos, gdb, macos-carbon, hotkeys

I want to create a replacement for the app switcher (aka 'cmd + tab').

I know that it's possible because Lite Switch X does it.

What I've got achieved so far:

By force quitting the dock and calling `CPSRegisterForKey()` (which is a private API function) I can prevent the default cmd+tab from working.

The second step is two register the hot key for my app. The standard way of doing this, `RegisterEventHotKey()`, doesn't work. A bit of googling and GDBing suggests that the Dock and Lite Switch X use `CGSSetHotKeyEnabled()` and `CGSSetHotKey()` (both of these are private API functions). The problem I have is that I do not know what arguments these functions take.

How can I determine the arguments for a private API function?

**Update:**

I've got a little further with `CGSSetHotKey()`:

`OSErr setupResult = CGSSetHotKey(_CGSDefaultConnection(), unknownArg, unknownArg, unknownArg, kCGEventFlagMaskCommand, ???, ???, ...);`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [class-dump](http://www.codethecode.com/projects/class-dump)? It's usually pretty helpful.

Comment: Close but no cigar! The calls are all plain-old C, not Objective-C. However, it was still useful. Thanks!

Comment: Whoops! You're absolutely correct. You could use `gdb` to attach to Finder, as you've done, but then you don't have symbols for these shared libraries. An interesting challenge…